# Unity Have the camera clamp to the camera y position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code for a camera follow.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraTracker : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float damping = 1;
public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

private float m_OffsetZ;
private Vector3 m_LastTargetPosition;
private Vector3 m_CurrentVelocity;
private Vector3 m_LookAheadPos;

[SerializeField]
private float xMax;
[SerializeField]
private float yMax;
[SerializeField]
private float xMin;
[SerializeField]
private float yMin;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.Find ("Player").transform;
    m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
    m_OffsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
    transform.parent = null;
}


// Update is called once per frame
private void Update()
{
    // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
    float xMoveDelta = (target.position - m_LastTargetPosition).x;

    bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

    if (updateLookAheadTarget)
    {
        m_LookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor*Vector3.right*Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
    }
    else
    {
        m_LookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(m_LookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime*lookAheadReturnSpeed);
    }

    Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + m_LookAheadPos + Vector3.forward*m_OffsetZ;
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);

    transform.position = newPos;

    m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x,xMin,xMax), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y,yMin,yMax), transform.position.z);

}
}
```

How would you make the yMax have no clamp?
Also, how can you make the yMin equal to the position of the bottom of the camera so that the minimum height changes as your camera moves upwards?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How would you make the yMax have no clamp?*

If you don't want to constrain the max value for Y, use `Mathf.Max` instead of `Mathf.Clamp`:

```
Mathf.Max(target.position.y,yMin)
```

*Also, how can you make the yMin equal to the position of the bottom of the camera so that the minimum height changes as your camera moves upwards?*

```
yMin = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
```

So your resulting `LateUpdate` method would be:

```
void LateUpdate()
{
    yMin = Camera.main.transform.position.y;

    transform.position = 
        new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x,xMin,xMax), 
            Mathf.Max(target.position.y, yMin), transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, really appreciate it :)

The code does what I asked but how could I stop the camera at 0 now that it is following the character?


Kind of new to c# and trying to get my head around it

Plus In case someone else wants the code above, you missed 'position' in the yMin =

Comment: `yMin = yMin > 0 ? yMin : 0` will ensure yMin stays above 0